# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error on local machine running xampp with php7

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel

I recently updated my xampp installation to current version with php7, however every thing seem to work fine until i tried testing out a laravel 5.2 project.
Accessing a page that doesn't make a database connection has no issue, but  trying accessing a route that makes a db query i get the error "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".

The error log doesn't really show any concrete errors that cause this.

```
[Fri Apr 22 20:50:41.365814 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 2856:tid 436] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Apr 22 20:50:41.422857 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2856:tid 436] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 22 20:50:41.422857 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2856:tid 436] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
[Fri Apr 22 20:50:41.422857 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2856:tid 436] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Apr 22 20:50:41.427857 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2856:tid 436] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7024
```

I have gone through php.ini configuration several times. What could cause this problem?